# Is it possbile to make files with a certain word be automatically moved to a specific folder?

Tags: files

I have a wallpapers folder under pictures and whenever I set any of them as wallpaper Ubuntu makes a copy of it that says "(copy)". How do I make them automatically move to a different folder?

Comment: In what location are the files name "(copy)" created?

Comment: In my wallpapers folder under pictures.

Comment: I don't seem to find such a file being created. What version of ubuntu are you using? On what filesystem is the wallpaper you are trying to set?

Comment: @Jobin I made the wallpapers folder, on ext4 on my home partition.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of files that have a certain word in it simply run this command:

```
ls | grep certain_word
```

then you will get all the files that have that word in their name then you can create a script that loop on the output and each result get copied to the different folder you want the example for the for loop you need and i think it will work with you after you do a script file is the following :

```
    for OUTPUT in $(Linux-Or-Unix-Command-Here)
    do
       command1 on $OUTPUT
       command2 on $OUTPUT
       commandN
    done
```

check this link for more info about bash scripting :

```
http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial
```